# Remove everything have the 'nth' comma in linux

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I will be honest that there are some similar questions on here, where I do not know how to interpret the answer. Any help would be appreciated. I have a string like this:

```
340,A,T,A,A,T,T,A,T,T,T,T,T,A,A,A,A
```

And I want to remove everything after the nth comma, in this example it could be the 5th comma though in reality it will be the 170th.

I tried this:

```
sed -i.back 's/,.*170//'
```

and this:

```
's/((?:[^,],){170}).((\s+\S+).*){1,}/$1/g'
```

Though clearly I don't know what I'm doing as the first reproduces the entire original file and the second generates no output.

Comment: With the additional comment that it is line after line like that, like 340,A,T,A,A,T,T,A,T,T,T,T,T,A,A,A,A 340,A,T,A,A,T,T,A,T,T,T,T,T,A,A,A,A 340,A,T,A,A,T,T,A,T,T,T,T,T,A,A,A,A and I want to do it to every line in the file

Answer (score 4):

Simplicity itself: (Note that the comma at the end is required.)

```
cut -f1-170 -d,
```

Comment: Nth comma will be missing from output so it doesn't fully meet `I want to remove everything after the nth comma` requirement

Answer (score 3):

Using awk you can do this:

```
s='340,A,T,A,A,T,T,A,T,T,T,T,T,A,A,A,A'
awk -v n=5 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {NF=n+1; $(n+1)=""} 1' <<< "$s"

340,A,T,A,A,
```

Or using `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/^(([^,]*,){5}).*/\1/' <<< "$s"

340,A,T,A,A,
```

Comment: `NF=n+1; $(n+1)=""` really clever! `++` A for-loop solution would look ugly before this

Comment: Thanks so much @Inian

Comment: This does not work, each line is not identical and I'm dealing with millions of lines and thousands of files. Apologies, they are just identical in the example.

Comment: Solution doesn't assume lines to be identical. Both `awk` and `sed` will delete text after Nth comma

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed);

```
sed 's/,/&\n/5;P;d' file
```

Insert a newline after the nth `,` print the first line in the pattern space and then delete everything else.